# IntelliJ Idea 2020 Malformed argument has embedded quote: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\"

Tags: intellij-idea

I just newly installed IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1, and when I run or build my project, I get this error：

> Error:Cannot run program "D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" (in
>   directory
>   "C:\Users\wukoubo\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\compile-server"):
>   Malformed argument has embedded quote: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\"

If I restart Idea, the error disappeared, but after a while, or after several times of building, this error appear again.

Comment: Please follow the related issues on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230268, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-238628

Answer (score 2):

In idea64 exe.vmoptions On the last line, add the code

```
-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I have upgraded to 2020.2, and this issue no longer exists